# Can I configure icecream (icecc) to do zero local jobs

Tags: build-system

I'm trying to build a project on a rather underpowered system (intel compute stick with 1GB of RAM). Some of the compilation steps run out of memory. I've configured icecc so that it can send some jobs to a more powerful machine, but it seems that icecc will always do at least one job on the local machine.

I've tried setting ICECC_MAX_JOBS="0" in /etc/icecc/icecc.conf (and restarting iceccd), but the comments in this file say:

```
# Note: a value of "0" is actually interpreted as "1", however it
# also sets ICECC_ALLOW_REMOTE="no".
```

I also tried disabling the icecc daemon on the compute stick by running `/etc/init.d/icecc stop`. However, it seems that icecc is still putting one job on the local machine (perhaps if the daemon is off it's putting all jobs on the local machine?).

The project is makefile based and it appears that I'm stuck on a bottleneck step where calling make with -j > 1 still only issues one job, and this compilation is expiring the system memory.

The only work around I can think of is to actually compile on a different system and then ship the binaries back over but I expect to enter a tweak/build/evaluate cycle on this platform so I'd like to be able to work from the compute stick directly.

Both systems are running ubuntu 14.04 if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not supported since if there are network issues, `icecc` resorts to compiling on the host machine itself. Best solution would be to compile on the remote machine and copy back the resulting binary.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `ICECC_TEST_REMOTEBUILD` in client's terminal (where you run `make`)?

```
export ICECC_TEST_REMOTEBUILD=1
```

In my tests this always forces all sources to be compiled remotely.

Just remember that linking is always done on local machine.